# Meteor react state passed to child component not updating

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

On the parent component I am trying to pass down the state ( which are just images ) down to 2 child components. One of the child components just displays the images.

The other child component has an event handler to change one of the images.
Here is my code I am getting no errors yet the image is not changing.. Thanks!

I am not including imports to cut down on code!

Parent component:

```
 export default class Parent extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
     super();   
         this.state = {
                 img1: <img id="img1" className="img-responsive center-block" name="img1" src="img1.png"/>,
                 img2: <img id="img2" className="img-responsive center-block" name="img2" src="" />
         };
    }



    render(){       
     return (  

            <div>

                            <displayBox layers={this.state}/>
                            <eventsBox layers={this.state}/>


            </div>


         ) 
    }
}
```

This is the display box component:

```
export default class AvatarCreationBox extends React.Component{


    render(){   


     return (                                           

                                    <div>
                                            {this.props.layers.img1}
                                            {this.props.layers.img2}
                                    </div>

         ) 
    }
```

}

Here is the other child component with the event handler:

It has this event handler that has been tested and works with a console.log at the end of it.

```
    itemClicked(itemId,event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            if(itemId === "img3"){
                    this.props.layers.img1 = <img className="media-object" src="img3.png" alt="..."/>;
                    console.log("yo");

            }
    }
```

Comment: you can not do something like this. Instead declare a function in you main class to maniplate the image and pass it down as props.

Comment: Ok I now have this function passed into the child and called but I am getting a undefined error:          renderView(){
               
                      
                                this.state.img1 = <img className="img-responsive center-block" src="img3.png" />;
                        }  it is passed in via: renderView={this.renderView} on the component in the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a function which manipulates the state in your parent class and pass it as prop. Next step is to call the function with new image inside your event class.

Change your Parent Class to this

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
     super();   
         this.state = {
                 img1: <img id="img1" className="img-responsive center-block" name="img1" src="img1.png"/>,
                 img2: <img id="img2" className="img-responsive center-block" name="img2" src="" />
         };

       this.changeImage = this. changeImage.bind(this)
    }

    changeImage(newImage){
        this.setState({img1: newImage});
    }

    render(){       
     return (  
            <div>
                <displayBox layers={this.state}/>
                <eventsBox 
                    layers={this.state}
                    callback={this.changeImage}/>
            </div>


         ) 
    }
}
```

and change event box code to following

```
itemClicked(itemId,event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(itemId === "img3"){
        this.props.callback('<img className="media-object" src="img3.png" alt="..."/>');
        console.log("yo");
    }
}
```

**Update:** React components using ES6 classes no longer autobind this to non React methods. In your constructor add

```
this.changeImage = this. changeImage.bind(this) in the constructor.
```

Comment: Thank you but I am now getting:  Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: Updated. The problem was in ES6 you have to manually bind this to your methods. So i have added this.changeImage = this. changeImage.bind(this) in the constructor.